# docker volume driver: unable to override existing file

Tags: docker

I'm writing a docker volume plugin that mounts a single file into the container. But I just found out that if the container image already has the file in it, this will fail with `readdirent: not a directory` error message.

I managed to reduce the driver into the simplest possible form: every API is stubbed with `Mount()` simply returns an existing host file path as `MountPoint`. It still results in the same error.

I'm wondering if this is a limitation by docker itself?

Comment: Is it a kernel version issue? (https://github.com/vmware/harbor/issues/2019#issuecomment-294397559)

Comment: I doubt it but I can try upgrading the kernel. Thanks

Comment: @VonC new kernel didn't solve it.

Comment: Ok, it was worth checking anyway